# Job seeking status is getting set to passive immediately after changing it to active

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

My job seeking status is currently set to "passive".  I don't want it to be passive, I want it to be active.  So I go and edit my profile to say that I am actively seeking a job.  A couple minutes later, I get an email stating that

> we haven't heard from you in a while, so we're setting you to passive.

What do I need to do to get this to stop happening?

Comment: I don't know why, but I read "Job seeking" as "Jon Skeet". He's controlling my mind :/

Comment: Are you updating this via the SO profile or in your Careers CV?

Comment: I can't update it via Careers at all because I'm pretty sure you guys have stopped caring about Opera 12 and my updated setting never saves.   The only way I can get it to change at all is via SO profile.

Comment: @cimmanon I'm going to push a fix for the issue above. Can you detail what problems you're having with Opera? We haven't intentionally broken anything and we'll fix any issues if you can let us know what the problem is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issue you mention. SO profile updates notify Careers via an internal API and it neglected to add the history records that are used by the scheduled job that resets your search state.

For the Opera issues: can you let us know what the problems are and we'll get them fixed up ASAP!